# Why is GSL-Lite trying to include <array>?

Tags: c++, keil, guideline-support-library

I'm trying to use a gsl inside my embedded STM32 Keil project. My Keil project uses an outdated semi c++11 compiler at most. (It is a constraint put on me by my ST library for LoRaWAN). I'm using the V5.06 update 6 (build 750) ARM Compiler bundled by keil. Keil has chosen not to implement the `std::aray` of the STL. I'm very disappointed about this but hey wat can I do.

I've chosen to use the [gsl-Lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite). It is supposed to be `C++98` and `C++03` compatible. So no `std::array` needed, but when I try to compile my code with the library included in my include path I get this build message:

> ..\Core\inc\gsl/gsl-lite.hpp(405): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "array": No such file or directory
> `# include <array>`

But [line 404](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl-lite.hpp#L404) starts with this piece of code:

```
#if gsl_HAVE( ARRAY )
# include <array>
#endif
```

Seems to me that they are trying to determine if `<array>` can be included. My editor greys this block out as if it hasn't been defined.

`gsl_HAVE` [is defined as:](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl-lite.hpp#L231)

```
#define gsl_HAVE(             feature )  ( gsl_HAVE_##feature )
```

I don't understand how this work and how I can check if `ARRAY` was properly not defined.

I wan't to not include `<array>` so my code can build and use the gsl-lite. My preferred option is something with a define.

## update

As far as I understand the include system:

```
#define gsl_HAVE_ARRAY                  gsl_CPP11_110
```

Is defined to automatically exclude a feature (`gsl_HAVE_ARRAY` in this case) when

```
#define gsl_CPP11_OR_GREATER  ( gsl_CPLUSPLUS >= 201103L )
```

Is evaluated to be true. `gsl_CPLUSPLUS` is defined as

```
#  define gsl_CPLUSPLUS  __cplusplus
```

But I can't seem to figure out the value of `__cplusplus`.

Comment: Have a search for `gsl_HAVE_ARRAY`.  That is coming up as defined which is breaking your build.

Comment: I think my problem is that `_cplusplus` holds no value because keil is annoying. Even when i declared `gsl_CPLUSPLUS` as `199711L` it didn't work because the compiler couldn't `delete` a `gsl::owner<int *>` because it is expecting a bare pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is that `_cplusplus` holds no value because keil doesn't add it. Even when I declared `gsl_CPLUSPLUS` as `199711L` it didn't work because the compiler couldn't `delete` a `gsl::owner<int *>` because it is expecting a bare pointer.

It seems like that the compiler just is too old to handle the gsl.